# Software for solving fractional differential equations numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, math-software, fractional-calculus

I have been trying to find information on how to solve fractional differential equations numerically with the usual maths software (Mathematica, Maple, Matlab, etc). Or to find an alternative program to do that.

I had no success.

Thanks.

Comment: One possibility would be to understand how to solve them, and implement it Mathematica, Maple, Matlab, Python, etc. Also, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956075/fractional-derivative-in-mathematica-maple

Answer (score 1):

Maple solves some fractional DE. For example, see http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/136505-Unable-To-Solve-Fractional-Differential .

Comment: What is showing this site is a way to reproduce in Maple the way you solve them but hand. But that procedure works only for linear FDE and is not a numerical method of integration.
Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MATLAB fde12 function. You may download it here:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32918

Its the easiest way.

Another example: [Software for Fractional Differential Equations and related problems:](https://www.dm.uniba.it/Members/garrappa/Software)